# What happens to a person who commits suicide according to Vedas and Bhagavd Gita

Tags: vedas, bhagavad-gita, atma

Can an atma harm or kill someone, can it gain superpowers like shape-shifting or superhuman strength? Can it communicate with other souls or with other living souls? Can it climb up the atma rank (from Atma to Brahmarakshasa)?

Please give references from Vedas and Srimad Bhagavadgita only.

Comment: What if Vedas and Bhagavad Gita don't have anything on the topic? Bhagavad Gita is a philosophical discourse and it can't be used to answer N number of valid Hinduism questions. A good asker is the one who can guess which scriptures are likely to have answers to their questions.

Comment: I don’t know whether you’ll respond (as you’ve not been responding to other answers posts, though you have unlocked commenting privileges, accepting questions and upvoting) but- 1. Firstly brahmarakshasa isn’t some atma rank. It’s a rakshasa who recites vedas. As far as climbing up the atma rank, all scriptures say person who commits suicide gets adhogati or downward gati (they become lower in rank). 2. When one dies, they are supposed to meet their deceased relatives (just like Kaurava & Pandava met in swarga) and yes they can communicate- you won’t find references for these in Gita and Vedas

Comment: After death, a person takes his sukshma sharira a body which is lighter than the earthly body and can move around more freely, so anyway a sukshma sharira is beyond human and therefore superhuman (it’s not something like a superhero movie where you’ll get laser eyes and lightning hammers). Moving freely is almost like floating/ flying due to lightweight. Only people with siddhis can see sukshma sharira but in all likelihood shapeshifting seems unlikely.

Comment: If ant or  any other animal dies iby suicide will it meet ant ancestors @Archit what will be sukshma sharia of ant which is committing sucide

Comment: @PrasannaR :D :D, no no not suicide, I meant natural death in all the above comments. Suicide is somewhat same but you won’t go to Pitrloka where your ancestors are. You’ll get downward gati and miserable state. Apparently I read miscellaneous sukshma Sharira is same as on earth, so I guess if an ant dies(natural) it will have a similar sukshma sharira

Comment: Āpastamba-dharma-sūtrá 1.9.25.3 exhorts one who drinks liquor to commit suicide by drinking glowing-hot wine. So suicide is listed as a punishment by Āpastamba.